# upgrading from Rails 3.x to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My company has several rails 3 apps (some ver 3.0.5 and some ver 3.2.11), and we are wanting to upgrade to a more recent version.  I'm trying to decide if we want to upgrade to 4.2 or 5, although it seems like we should go to 5 if possible since that is the most recent.  In the official guide for [upgrading RoR](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) there are guidelines for going from 3.x to 4.x but nothing for going from 3.x to 5.x.  Not really finding anything useful on google. Is an upgrade from 3.x to 5.x too big of a leap? Any links, resources, or advice from anyone who has gone this route before would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go from 3 to 4, then from 4 to 5 (guides exist for these paths). You can't expect devs to go and write N-1 migration guides for all previous versions when version N gets released.

Comment: Questions looking for off-site resources or tutorials are not allowed here. Sorry you didn't read the rules first.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev. I kinda thought that would be the case, but was hoping there might be a simple way to go directly to ver 5